# I want to capture multiple key event at once

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <textarea id="txtarea"></textarea>
        <script>
            var map = [];
            $('#txtarea').onkeydown = $('#txtarea').onkeyup = function(e){
                e = e || event; // to deal with IE
                map[e.keyCode] = e.type == 'keydown';
                if(map[13] && map[16])
                    alert("Its Working!!");
                else
                    alert("Its not working !!");
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**I want to capture multiple mouse event at once.Where is the error in this.If there is nay better way to do is then please let me know. Thanks in advance.**

Comment: how can you have a `keydown` in a  `keyup` event?

Comment: There is no keydown in a keyup in that code..... `var a = b = 3;`, but the code is invalid since that is not how jQuery works.

Comment: Oh i got a way . By the way thanks all for your help

Comment: As far as I can tell, you're trying to test whether Shift+Enter is pressed. Just test for `e.keyCode === 13 && e.shiftKey`.

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
  <textarea id="txtarea"></textarea>
  <script>
   var map = [];
   $('#txtarea').keydown(function(e){
    map[e.keyCode] = true;
   });
   $('#txtarea').keyup(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 13 && map[16])
     alert("Its Working");
    else
     alert("its not working");
    map[16] = false;
   });
  </script>
    </body>
</html>`

Comment: I am new here.Sorry for the bad format .Its not getting formatted.

Comment: @ Phylogenesis yea , I am trying the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change

```
$('#txtarea').onkeydown = $('#txtarea').onkeyup = function(e){
            e = e || event; // to deal with IE
            map[e.keyCode] = e.type == 'keydown';
            if(map[13] && map[16])
                alert("Its Working!!");
            else
                alert("Its not working !!");
        }
```

to

```
$('#txtarea').bind("keyup keydown", function(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 13] || e.keyCode === 16) {
        alert("Its Working!!");
    } else {
        alert("Its not working !!");
    }
});
```

then it should work for either event.

Answer (score 1):

You can't capture multiple events at once, only one event will fire at any given moment and JavaScript doesn't do threading.

It looks like you are actually trying to define multiple event handlers at once, but you have your syntax wrong.

jQuery doesn't support `onkeydown` etc properties.

You need to use the `on` method.

The `events` argument is a string containing space separated list of events.

```
$('#txtarea').on("keydown keyup", yourFuntion);
```

---

```
e = e || event; // to deal with IE
```

Don't do that. jQuery normalises event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) you can bind to multiple events by separating them with a space.

```
$('#txtarea').on('keyup keydown', function (e){
  // (fires for both keyup and keydown events)
  // console.log(e) 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As per our discussion above, you are trying to trigger an action when Shift-Enter is pressed. You can reduce your code above to the following:

```
$('#txtarea').on(
    'keydown',
    function (e) {
        if (e.shiftKey && e.keyCode === 13) {
            // Shift-Enter has been pressed!
        }
    }
);
```